# (Orange/cream/violet) + ish

Tags: word-usage

As you know, the words like "reddish" or "greenish" mean "slightly red" or "slightly green". The same goes with some other color adjectives like "blue/yellow/etc".
But I need to know if this structure can be applied to some other colors like "orange", "cream" and "violet" too?

I.e. do the words "orangish", "creamish" and "violetish" standard words in English?
I am asking this question because I could not find them in dictionaries.

Comment: I think we use -ish with primary colours, and black or white. We can use -ey or -y with any shade, e.g. her dress was a kind of pinky-orangey colour.

Comment: Do you mean that "violetey" and "creamey" work @Michael Harvery?

Comment: Please define "work". Note: creamy.

Comment: By "work" I meant "are they correct words?" Also, I think "creamy" is exactly the same as "cream". What do you think on that @Micahel Harvey?

Comment: Everyone would know what you meant if you added the suffix _-ish_ to an adjective, but words like _violetish_ are not sufficiently widely used to have made it into dictionaries.

Comment: @A-friend - 'cream' is the fatty part of milk, or its colour (nouns); 'creamy' is an adjective meaning 'like cream in some way'.

Comment: [***Violetish***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22violetish%22) might sound a bit "clunky" in isolation like that, but it's far from unknown. I even found [***magnoliaish***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Magnoliaish%2C+and+I%22), but I don't think that example was intended to mean ***not exactly creamish, more like magnolia-coloured***.

Comment: Well @FumbleFingers Reinstate I think according to your and Kate's replies, we are allowed to make such words and despite "orangish", "creamish" and "violetish" are not standard English words, but they can make an acceptable sense. Do you agree?

Comment: Well, yes - up to a point. But this is dangerous territory for non-native speakers. Personally, I will accept an awful lot of neologisms and "creative morphological inflections" from someone I consider to be a competent native speaker. But if I think their command of English is *significantly* less than mind (and/or they're a non-native Anglophone), I'd probably become *much* more "picky". What it comes down to is more or less that I'll accept practically ***anything*** provided I can understand it, ***and*** it came from a competent native speaker. If not, all bets are off.

Comment: Point taken FumbleFimgers. Agreed. You are absolutely right. The same goes with me with all languages I can consider myself a (semi)native person in. That was a quite reasonable answer.